# iPhone (iOS 7) App Icon Strange Behaviour

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, icons

I am facing the problem with the App Icon on the iOS 7 Device, the Problem is : I am getting a black border on the top corner of the icon. The Icon size & Name i used is:

```
Size :  120 X 120 pixels

Name :   Icon-60@2x.png
```

(Sorry, I can't post the screen shot/Image here as i need 10 reputation points to post an image. Hope you guys understands)

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance !

EDIT:

Comment: I've upvoted so you can an the image. Please can you add it.

Comment: It seems that you have a transparent zone (filled by default with black). Check you icone.

Comment: linked your image in some where sever like dropbox, google dirve etc.,

Comment: Just looks like you have added the rounded corners yourself there is no need for this as iOS will do this for you. There is no point in me giving an answer as the rest are correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

iOS [HIG guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW1) suggest,

> **Avoid transparency**. An app icon should be opaque. If the icon’s boundaries are smaller than the recommended sizes—or you use transparency to create “see-through” areas—the resulting icon can appear to float on a black background, which tends to look especially unattractive on the beautiful wallpapers that users choose.

Check if there is any transparency present in the icon, if yes, please remove it.

You should avoid rounded corner icon, because Apple applies masks to your icon image for this. Provide a sqaure-ish icon of dimensions 120x120 pixels.

[image]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

For iPhone and iPod touch, both of these sizes are required:

120 x 120 pixels

60 x 60 pixels (standard resolution)

[image]

Reference by [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/AppIcons.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've faced same issue like this. I'd provided image with `rounded corner`. When I provide **flat image** with this size, I'll see correct icon. Seems to be silly. But It has work.

Answer (score 1):

**Please try these steps**

STEP 1:Remove the transparency of app icon.
STEP 2:Add square images. Images with rounded corners also make this issue